# Obtain permission to do something or obtain a permit allowing somebody to do something

Tags: expressions

Could you tell me if these sentence is appropriate ? I know it is correct though. But, sounds to me odd. "the Jewish community in Parczew managed **to obtain a permit allowing them to transport** the 200 bodies of people shot in Juliopol and bury them in the cemetery in Parczew."

The part of the sentence in bold is rather sensless I would say *to obtain a permission/permit to transport...* because if there is a permit we already know that it allows something. Am I right ?

Comment: A "permit" is a physical piece of paper (or, I suppose, its on-line equivalent in modern times).  In most cases it officially conveys "permission" to do something.  It is generally signed/stamped by the relevant "authority".

Comment: it's perfectly correct, and has nothing to do with this site.  we're stealing this from the ELL site.

Answer (score 7):

They didn't get "a permission", they got "a permit" in the sense of an actual document that certifies the permission they have.

Now, obviously a permit allows something, but there's no redundancy because we are informed:

1. That they have such a document.
2. What the document allows.

Saying "they got permission to" does not tell us about the document. Saying they got a permit does not clarify what the permit allowed. The phrase "…a permit allowing…" allows both to be concisely conveyed.

Answer (score 3):

**"Permit *allowing* them"** may seem a bit redundant at first glance, but the addition of *"allowing them"*, may be meant to convey that the permitted action was carried out.

Comment: Correctamundo. It's like saying '...obtained a permit _enabling_ them'. +1